# How can I properly set a type for `useState`, if I want the piece of state to either be an object or null?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm having a little trouble using Typescript with React and `useState`.

Say I have something like,

```
type TPerson = {
  name: string;
  car: string;
};
export default function App() {
  const [person, setPerson] = React.useState<TPerson>(null);

  const handleClear = React.useCallback(() => {
    setPerson(null);
  }, []);

  const { name, car } = person;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>
        {person.name} drives a {person.car}
      </h1>
      <button onClick={handleClear}>clear</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This would complain here,

```
  const handleClear = React.useCallback(() => {
    setPerson(null);
              ^^^^
              Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type
  }, []);
```

Well, ok, let's fix that by changing up `TPerson`,

```
type TPerson = {
  name: string;
  car: string;
} | null;
```

That fixes that error, but now I get a new one,

```
<h1>
    {person.name} drives a {person.car}
            ^^^^                   ^^^
            Object is possibly 'null'.
</h1>
```

Well that's easy, I'll just do,

```
<h1>
    {person?.name ?? 'unknown name'} drives a {person?.car ?? 'unknown car'}
</h1>
```

But then I get this error,

```
const { name, car } = person;
        ^^^^  ^^^
        Properties 'name' and 'car' do not exist on type 'TPerson'
```

Well, yeah, I guess, because `TPerson` can be `null`.

I can't even do,

```
const { name = '', car = '' } = person;
```

or,

```
type TPerson = {
  name: string;
  car: string;
};
. . .
const [person, setPerson] = React.useState<TPerson>({} as TPerson);
```

So what are my options here? If I have a modal that determines it's `open` state on whether or not `person` is null, how can I properly go about this?

Comment: Why can't you use `React.useState<TPerson | null>(null)`? And then wrap everything in one `if (person)`?

Comment: you can init your varialbe using setState({name = '', car = ''}) and avoid all trouble, using "{}" instead of null can reduce your troubles, using null just to avoid "if-else" is not very pratical since you are going into more troubles by saving one "if", by the way "{}" will work same as null in most of the cases

Answer (score 0):

You could set the type of `useState` to `TPerson | undefined` and then check if the properties are null.

Example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-cdn-gx9kt?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem with React. It's how typescript works. You need to understand how type narrowing works in typescript to understand this.

```
// if we have the type below
type MaybePerson = { name: string } | null 

const me: MaybePerson; // me can either be null or an object with the key name

// if we try to access name on me i.e
me.name; // typescript will complain given that `me` can be `null` and `null` doesn't have the property name.

// We can fix this by:-
// 1. If you are sure that me is never null. You can use the non null assertion operator
me!.name

// 2. narrow down the type to person i.e
if(me !== null){
  // me in this block will be an object
  me.name
  
  // you can even destructure me here safely
  const { name } = me
}
```

Now going back to your react code.
One alternative is to render something different when person is null.

```
type TPerson = {
  name: string;
  car: string;
};

export default function App() {
  // make the type you pass to useState, TPerson | null
  const [person, setPerson] = React.useState<TPerson | null>(null);

  const handleClear = React.useCallback(() => {
    setPerson(null);
  }, []);
 
  if(!person){
    // return some thing else or just null
    return null
  }
  
  // person here will be a TPerson object and you can destructure it safely
  const { name, car } = person;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>
        {person.name} drives a {person.car}
      </h1>
      <button onClick={handleClear}>clear</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Or you can as well ignore the condition that narrows down the type and specify a default value when person is null i.e

```
// outside your component
const defaultPerson: TPerson = { name: '', car: '' }

// in your component
const { name, car } = person || defaultPerson;
```

Also, you can just use the default value instead of ever using null i.e

```
type TPerson = {
  name: string;
  car: string;
};

const defaultPerson: TPerson = { name: '', car: '' }

export default function App() {
  // use defaultValue
  const [person, setPerson] = React.useState<TPerson>(defaultPerson);

  const handleClear = React.useCallback(() => {
    // set this to defaultPerson
    setPerson(defaultPerson);
  }, []);

  const { name, car } = person;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>
        {person.name} drives a {person.car}
      </h1>
      <button onClick={handleClear}>clear</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```